# Replacing list items using a dict

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I'm currently trying to fix this piece of code i've been writing recently. It should take a list and a dict(below), then if an item in the list matches an item in the dictionary, it should append it to a list. I know that it is trying to match the items in the list with the wrong part of the dict, but I do not know how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]   
{'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3}

text_print('\nPlease input your file location: ')
    location = input()
    with open(location) as f:
        c = literal_eval(f.readline())
        d = literal_eval(f.readline())
    n_string = []
    text_print(str(c))
    text_print('\n')
    text_print(str(d))
    for item in c:
        if item in d:
            n_string.append(str(item))
    text_print(str(n_string))
```

The code should output a b c d etc

Comment: Why don't switch keys and values in the dictionnary, i.e. `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}` instead of `{'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3}` ?

Comment: Do want to match items in the list to **keys**, **values** or **items** in the dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the dictionary to see if any of the values in the list are in the dictionary. If present, append the key to the `result` list.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
my_dict = {'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3,'d':3,'e':15}

result = []
for num in my_list:
   for key,value in my_dict.items():
      if num == value:
         result.append(key)

print result
```

**Output:**

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

To reduce the number of comparisons you can get an intersection of the list and the dictionary keys and iterate over that.

```
set(my_list).intersection(my_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand the purpose of the files. Could you give more information on this? In your example, is "c" the list or the dictionary? And what is "d"?

Anyway, in your loop you are just comparing the keys of the dictionary to the items of the list, so none will match seeing as the items of the list are the numbers and the keys of the dictionary are the letters. **You need to compare the values of the dictionary** to the items of your list. I have given you an example below.

```
yourlist = [1,3]   
yourdict = {'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3}

n_string = []
for key in yourdict:
    if yourdict[key] in yourlist:
        n_string.append(key)

print(n_string)
```

This example does parse the dictionary and check whether its values are in the list. If the value (number) is in the list, then it adds the key (letter) to the output list.

Comment: Please don't name variables like builtins, i.e. don't use `dict` and `list` as names!

Comment: Sorry there, new to this website, I thought it would be clear. You are right! I have edited my response to fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

You should switch keys and values in the `dict`. Assuming you cannot change the input, you can convert the dict after loading it:

```
d2 = {val: key for key, val in d.items()}
```

Then you can directly look up items.

```
for item in c:
    try:
        n_string.append(str(d2[item]))
    except KeyError:
        pass
text_print(str(n_string))
```

Comment: What happens if a value repeats?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham By the definition of your problem, this is undefined. What will happen in practice is that upon conversion, only one of these values will be preserved. For each key:value with the same value, it's the last pair read, though the order of reading pairs is arbitrary.

Comment: @MisterMyagi, it was more a rhetorical question. You cannot safely switch the values and keys. apart from the issue with potentially losing data  you also need hashable values which may not always be the case

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Did it occur to you that these restrictions are quite important, and should be part of a question if relevant?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That this "restriction" is relevant is predicated upon the assumption that OP had this solution in mind. :)

Comment: @erip It's predicated on the common types one uses when having such a problem. He's using `literal_eval`, so only `dict`, `set` and `list` types could break this. Yet his example specifically uses `int` and `str` types, i.e. not collections (unless assuming that `str` is meant to represent arbitrary containers...).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are checking the dict in the comparison with list item `if item in d`. Fetch the dict values `d.vales()` and do the comparison. After the `n_string` values are fetched in this operation, run a for loop with the keys, values as demonstrated below:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]   
{'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3}

text_print('\nPlease input your file location: ')
    location = input()
    with open(location) as f:
        c = literal_eval(f.readline())
        d = literal_eval(f.readline())
    n_string = []
    nn_string = []
    text_print(str(c))
    text_print('\n')
    text_print(str(d))
    for item in c:
        if item in d.values():
            n_string.append(str(item))
    text_print(str(n_string))

    for itemcur in n_string:
        for key, value in d.iteritems():
            if str(value) == str(itemcur):
                nn_string.append(str(key))
    print(str(nn_string))
```

Please take care of indentation error if any. Provide the necessity spaces!